# Tiny Wings - Placing items

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm currently developing a Flash game like 'Tiny Wings'. I have a lot of work done, but i'm currently working on placing the items ( coins and obstacles ) on the terrain.

My player it is moving on a auto-generated terrain (based on Emanuele Feronato's tutorials) so every time the player's x position is greater than (screenWidth + x) another hill is generated and so on.

I'm currently having problems placing the items in a correct angle and put 5 or more items together on a hill.

Could you please help me with this?

Thanks,
Regards.

PS: This is the URL to the Emanuele Feronato post and the code to make the hills
http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2011/10/04/create-a-terrain-like-the-one-in-tiny-wings-with-flash-and-box2d-%E2%80%93-adding-more-bumps/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just find the hill-element that's at the position where you want to place your item and rotate it to match the orientation of the hill-element. You can get the angle of the element by doing something like this (please note that the angle will be in radians):

```
segment = vertexB - vertexA
angle = atan2(segment.y, segment.x)
```

Personally, I would just store the vertices (vectors) that make out the slope of the terrain in a separate data-structure, because reading them out from the box2d bodies can be cumbersome. To find `vertexA` and `vertexB` given a desired item-position `itemX`, you would iterate through the hill-vertices (assuming they are ordered from left to right) and stop whenever `vertices[currentIndex].x` is bigger than `itemX`. Then `vertexB` will be `vertices[currentIndex]` and `vertexA` will be `vertices[currentIndex - 1]`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm trying to implement it as you describe.

Answer (score 1):

@bummzack is correct; use trigonometry.  also worth noting is the 2d perpendicular vector to a segment is

```
(-segment.y, segment.x) or (segment.y, -segment.x)
```

notice the dot product with the segment in both cases is zero (because cos(90) = 0)